# How to wait till all workers thread in threadPools are gone

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, threadpool

Anyone knows the easy way to do so?

Basically after I queue all works, I want to wait until all I queued has been done. How do I do so?

```
   loopThroughAllBlog(whattodo, login)'queue all works
```

//what to do here to wait till all queued works are done.

```
    Dim whatToWrite = New Generic.List(Of String)
    For Each domain In domainsSorted
        whatToWrite.Add(dictionaryOfOutput.Item(domain))
    Next
    coltofile(whatToWrite, "output.txt", True)
```

I notice there is no way to know how many threads are still running in the threadpool.

Comment: Are you looking for thread joins?  From the calling process (or thread) you should wait for the thread to join before you proceed.

Comment: I can do thread joins but how do I know the threads in the threadpools?

Comment: Hope this should get u started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up answering my own question because there is no answer.

```
Public Function threadPoolIdle() As Boolean
    Dim workerThreads As Integer
    Dim completionPorts As Integer
    Dim maxWorkerThreads As Integer
    Dim maxCompletionPorts As Integer
    Dim stillWorking As Integer

    Threading.ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(workerThreads, completionPorts)
    Threading.ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(maxWorkerThreads, maxCompletionPorts)
    stillWorking = maxWorkerThreads + maxCompletionPorts - workerThreads - completionPorts

    If stillWorking > 0 Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If

End Function

Public Sub waitTillThreadPoolisIdle()
    Do
        Sleep(1000)
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop While threadPoolIdle() = False
End Sub
```

I think this is just awkward. There has to be a better way.

Comment: Guys the answer I wrote works. Well this is the one I actually used :)

Answer (score 4):

A common way of achieving this is using a counter, protected by a semaphore.  (It seems to me your code is VB.  I don't know VB, so my syntax is probably off, treat it like pseudocode).

First you need to set up the semaphore and the counter:

```
' a semaphore is a counter, you decrease it with WaitOne() and increase with Release()
' if the value is 0, the thread is blocked until someone calls Release()
Dim lock = new Semaphore(0, 1)
Dim threadcount = 10 ' or whatever
```

At the end of the function being run by the threadpool, you need to decrease the thread-counter, and release the lock if threadcount is 0

```
threadcount = threadcount - 1
if threadcount = 0 then
    lock.Release()
end if
```

when waiting for your threads, try to aquire the semaphore, which will block until someone calls release:

```
lock.WaitOne()
```

for the decrease-and-check operation above, you would probably want to put that in a separate subroutine.  You also need to protect this so that each thread that tries to access the counter is isolated from other threads.

```
dim counterMutex = new Mutex()
sub decreaseThreadCount()
    counterMutex.WaitOne()
    threadcount = threadcount - 1
    if threadcount = 0 then
        lock.Release()
    end if
    counterMutex.release()
end sub
```

Comment: I see the link Vijay provided uses WaitHandle which seems to be a more high-level approach to achieve the same.  My answer is the text-book example of synchronization using semaphores, WaitHandle seems to be a more high-level application of the same principles.

Comment: If you want notification on your main thread, (as you seem to do), it's more common for the last thread, (the one that decrements the thread-safe counter to 0), to Invoke/BeginInvoke a signal/message onto the main thread, so not blocking it during the thread/threadpool activity.

Comment: @JimThio who tricked you into believing that multi-threading was easy? ;-)  This is typically taught in basic courses in operating systems.  http://people.csail.mit.edu/rinard/osnotes/h3.html  But .net has obviously simplified this by building some common abstractions, ref the link from CSharpVJ

Comment: ..and has ~500ms latency and DoEvents() :(